# Textview highlight while audio.mp3 is playing

Tags: android-studio

I have layrics in textview . And a button to play audio file. But i want to know how we can highlight the textview word when we click on play button.

MediaPlayer play;

TextView textView4;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third_kalma);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

    if (play.isPlaying()) {

        textView4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent p = new Intent(Third.this,ThirdT.class);
            startActivity(p);
        }
    });

    play = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.audio3);
    Button bone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSec);
    bone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            play.start();
        }});}
```

Comment: Hi Mohassan Noon, try out this for warning or error : mTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(SignUpActivity.this,R.color.black));

Comment: THANKS Sir Ram Koti, for reply , although it did not work my code is this

Comment: textView4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black)); keep this line after play.start() line, so it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, it will be helpful:
try to keep this code in timer or scheduler:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#Your own color code(#ff0000)")); 
}
```

or you can try this:

```
final Button play= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("your color code"));
            }
        });
```

or you can try scheduler like:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler =
                (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#Your own color code(#ff0000)")); 
                    }
                    }
        }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: dear sir Ram Koti, im still unable to do , error is setTextColor, could not resolve it

Comment: try out this mTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(SignUpActivity.this,R.color.black));

Comment: Hi Mohassan Noon please check the above line:

Comment: Sir Ram Koti i have code above could you find out in that what is the error, sorry for the disturbance sir,

Comment: Thank You very much Sir Ram Koti, its working now , changed color, but is it possible to color it with word to word, or its background color word to word,

Comment: sorry mohassan noon I didn't understand, what is meant by word to word?  do you want to change the color of the word to word in a sentence(text view) or need to change the color of sentence based upon song selection? so that i can suggest you to what to do.

Comment: Word by word sorry for the bad english. Need to change the sentence (text view ). Thanks sir

Comment: edit this line textView4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black)); which you have return in play.start() to the following code:
declare a global variable name it as int count=0,  and write this code in play.start():

if(count==0){
textView4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
count++;
}
else{
textView4.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red));
count--;
}

Comment: dear sir Ram Koti its still gives me same result as befor, changes the color of entire text in textview , i wanted to change it word by word, is it possible?